npm install error throw Error: Expected "0.20.2" but got "" in vue project
I am new to Vue frontend applications and created a brand new Vue project and when I am installing the NPM packages using the command npm install, I'm getting the below error message:
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\UserA\Projects\Vue\sample-project\node_modules\esbuild
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node install.js
npm ERR! C:\Users\UserA\Projects\Vue\sample-project\node_modules\esbuild\install.js:133
npm ERR!     throw new Error(`Expected ${JSON.stringify(versionFromPackageJSON)} but got ${JSON.stringify(stdout)}`);
npm ERR!           ^
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Error: Expected "0.20.2" but got ""
npm ERR!     at validateBinaryVersion (C:\Users\UserA\Projects\Vue\sample-project\node_modules\esbuild\install.js:133:11)
npm ERR!     at C:\Users\UserA\Projects\Vue\sample-project\node_modules\esbuild\install.js:284:5
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Node.js v20.12.2

I have uninstalled and reinstalled node.js and tried couple of times still getting the same error.
I am trying to run the Vue application in Windows but getting errors when installing the npm esbuild package.

Check for existing issues or raise a new one ~ https://github.com/evanw/esbuild/issues?q=is%3Aissue+validateBinaryVersion+is%3Aopen
